# I'm a little bit puzzled by the condition of the second derivative.

Tags: calculus

Here is the problem.

Suppsose that $f$ is a twice-differentiable function of the set of real numbers and that $f(0),f'(0) \text{and} f''(0)$ are all negative. Suppose $f''$ has all three of the following properties.

I.It is increasing on the interval $[0,\infty)$

II.It has a unique zero in the interval $[0,\infty)$

III. It is unbounded on the interval $[0,\infty)$

Which of the same three properties does $f$ necessarily have ?

My question is this.
How can $f''$ stay negative when it is increasing and have a unique zero ?
I thought about it being 0 at x = 0, then remaining equal to 0, but that would contradict the fact that it is increasing and the fact that the zero is unique.

I am starting to think that I am missing a huge hole here.
Can someone help me out ?

Comment: You have $\exists c \in [0, \infty), f''(c)=0$ and $\forall x,y \in x \ge y \Rightarrow f''(x)\ge f''(y)$ so $\exists !c \in [0, \infty), f''(c)=0 \land \forall x > c, f''(x)> 0$...

Comment: By the way, what makes you think it should remain negative? It only tells you that it's negative at a given point, not that it remains negative on the whole interval...

Comment: Thanks for telling me that. After 2 hours of constant thinking and calculating, I think my brain stopped working to it's potential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Nothing in conditions I-III requires $f''$ to stay negative; on the contrary, they imply that $f''$ does **not** stay negative. Since $f''$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$ and has a unique zero, either

1. $f''(0)=0$, and $f''(x)>0$ for all $x>0$, or
2. $f''(0)<0$, there is a unique $c>0$ such that $f''(c)=0$, $f''(x)<0$ for $0\le x<c$, and $f''(x)>0$ for $x>c$.

To this we can add the information, inferrable from III, that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f''(x)=\infty$.

Once you’ve figured out what happens in case (2), you can easily modify it to see what happens in case (1), so let’s look at (2): $f\,'$ is decreasing on $[0,c]$, increasing on $[c,\infty)$, and has a horizontal tangent and minimum at $x=c$. Moreover, not only is $f\,'$ increasing on $[c,\infty)$, but its slope $f''$ is increasing as well, so $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f\,'(x)=\infty$. From this you should be able to make a qualitatively decent sketch of the graph $y=f\,'(x)$; the one thing that you cannot do is locate the graph vertically, in relation to the $x$-axis. In particular, the graph could lie entirely above the $x$-axis; it could be tangent to the $x$-axis; it could cross the $x$-axis twice; or it could start below the $x$-axis and cross the $x$-axis just once. You’ll need to take these possibilities into account in thinking about the possible characteristics of $f$.

However, you do know that (the graph of) $f$ is concave down on $[0,c]$ and concave up on $[c,\infty)$, so $f$ has an inflexion point at $x=c$. You also know that $f\,'(x)$ is positive for all sufficiently large $x$; why, and what does this tell you about the behavior of $f$?

Comment: That was perfect helping, thank you !

Comment: @hyg17: You’re very welcome.